# Redirecting POST JSON data to another page to display

Tags: php, redirect, post

I currently have a program that will run tests on a server and it will send the results to the test.php file. I am trying to redirect my POST data to reports.php page, this data is in JSON format and I want to display the data on the page in reports.php nicely (eventually). Right now I just want to echo the result of the POST on my reports.php so I can troubleshoot and improvise my code. How can I do this? Currently, when I open the report.php I get a blank white page.  This is what I have in my test.php file.

test.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// turn on error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//URL to POST JSON data to
$url = "http://my/dir/to/reports.php";

$post_data = array(
  'id' => $argv[1],
  'version' => $argv[2],
  'server' => $argv[3],
  'status' => $argv[4],
  'test' => $argv[5],
  'time' => $argv[6],
  'body' => $argv[7],
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo "success: \n\n";
    print_r($result);
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

reports.php

```
<?php  //reports.php
//This php file is to receive the POST data coming from php files.
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $token = $_POST['result'];
    echo print_r($token);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First observation. In results.php you have the following:

```
echo print_r($token);
```

You echo, or you print_r(), you don't do both. Echo will output a string, print_r() will output a string or a human readable version of an object or an array. print_r() can be good for testing, but your final code should echo any output you want to print to the page.

Anyway, as for your question...

It seems like you are getting a bit confused with your variable names between your two php files, namely `$result`.

Here is your POST data from test.php, the keys in this array will become the keys in the $_POST array which will be posted to reports.php:

```
$post_data = array(
  'id' => $argv[1],
  'version' => $argv[2],
  'server' => $argv[3],
  'status' => $argv[4],
  'test' => $argv[5],
  'time' => $argv[6],
  'body' => $argv[7],
);
```

So `$_POST['id'], $_POST['version']` etc will be set in reports.php

Now here's your code for results.php:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $token = $_POST['result'];
    echo print_r($token);
}
```

You are referencing `$_POST['result']` but result is not one of the array keys you are posting, so it will not be set and your output will be empty. You have defined `$result` as the variable in test.php which will contain the response from reports.php, but within reports.php it's undefined.

As you want all the content back in the response from reports.php then specifying an array key for `$_POST` is unnecessary, just return the whole array.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

Or if you want it as JSON:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    echo json_encode($_POST);
}
```

Finally, with reference to this:

> Currently, when I open the report.php I get a blank white page

If you are opening it in your browser then it will be blank, as you are making a GET request, not a POST request. It will only return content if you POST data to it.

Having said all this I feel like you are trying to reinvent the wheel a bit with this approach. My recommendation would be to check out [RequestBin](https://requestb.in/) where you can create a URL to POST data to and inspect all the requests coming from your server. It's great for debugging and it's free.

Comment: Wow this is very helpful!! thank you so much for the detailed response. let me read it over a few more times and ill ask you questions if I have any. Thanks again!!

Comment: just to make sure I'm doing this correctly, for the request bin, I just set the `$url` in my `test.php` to the request bin's URL and do I retrieve it in my `reports.php` ? ` $result = file_get_contents('https://requestb.in/1i8lmm81');`
     `echo $result;`? I tried this but my reports.php is still blank. However, I do see the post data in the request bin page after I refresh.

Comment: No need to alter your reports.php You just inspect the request bin in your browser by refreshing as you have done and debug that way. Once you have it working as you expect then you point it back at your reports.php

Comment: Hi miknik, last question for you. So I can successfully see all the POST data in my request bin, now I want to be able to use that data to present it in the `reports.php` page. I changed the `$url` in my script to point back to `reports.php` and using the way you suggested above to retrieve the data `$_POST['id'], $_POST['version']` however, when I echoed these variables am I supposed to be able to see the result of the echo? where would I be able to see them? Or how can I use them? My intent is to generate a link for each POST result, and when user clicks on the link it will display it.

Comment: Where the data goes depends upon how it is requested. In your current setup everything you echo from reports.php will go into the $result variable in test.php. How you use it is up to you to configure, personally I would post this as an ajax request and return JSON from reports.php and process the response with javascript. This way you can update the page without reloading it.

Comment: Hi miknik, what if I cannot change the `test.php` file too much and want to keep this setup. I need something just like the requestbin to show my POST data instead of returning it back to `$result`. How can I accomplish this?